# How to create Pandas groupby plot with subplots

Tags: python, pandas, plot, group-by, subplot

I have a data frame like this:

```
     value     identifier
2007-01-01  0.781611      55
2007-01-01  0.766152      56
2007-01-01  0.766152      57
2007-02-01  0.705615      55
2007-02-01  0.032134      56 
2007-02-01  0.032134      57
2008-01-01  0.026512      55
2008-01-01  0.993124      56
2008-01-01  0.993124      57
2008-02-01  0.226420      55
2008-02-01  0.033860      56
2008-02-01  0.033860      57
```

So I do a groupby per identifier:

```
df.groupby('identifier')
```

And now I want to generate subplots in a grid, one plot per group. I tried both

```
df.groupby('identifier').plot(subplots=True)
```

or

```
df.groupby('identifier').plot(subplots=False)
```

and

```
plt.subplots(3,3)
df.groupby('identifier').plot(subplots=True)
```

to no avail. How can I create the graphs?

Comment: check out `seaborn`, it does this really nicely.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to avoid seaborn and use matplotlib only instead. Dependencies and Windows environment, etc etc.

Comment: Old comment, but `seaborn` is an API for `matplotlib`. Seaborn reduces this to 1 line without any dataframe transformations: `sns.relplot(kind='line', data=df.reset_index(), row='identifier', x='index', y='value')`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's an automated layout with lots of groups (of random fake data) and playing around with `grouped.get_group(key)` will show you how to do more elegant plots.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame(randint(0,10,(200,6)),columns=list('abcdef'))
grouped = df.groupby('a')
rowlength = grouped.ngroups/2                         # fix up if odd number of groups
fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,4), 
                        nrows=2, ncols=rowlength,     # fix as above
                        gridspec_kw=dict(hspace=0.4)) # Much control of gridspec

targets = zip(grouped.groups.keys(), axs.flatten())
for i, (key, ax) in enumerate(targets):
    ax.plot(grouped.get_group(key))
    ax.set_title('a=%d'%key)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You mentioned fix if odd, so: rowlength = grouped.ngroups/2 + (0 if grouped.ngroups % 2 == 0 else 1)

Comment: It's helpful to understand that the reason this works is that you generate a bunch of axes, and pass each axis object in turn to each group being plotted. You're filling each subfigure with a sub-group plot. Neat!

Answer (score 19):

You could use `pd.pivot_table` to get the `identifiers` in columns and then call `plot()`

```
pd.pivot_table(df.reset_index(),
               index='index', columns='identifier', values='value'
              ).plot(subplots=True)
```

[image]

And, the output of

```
pd.pivot_table(df.reset_index(),
               index='index', columns='identifier', values='value'
               )
```

Looks like -

```
identifier        55        56        57
index
2007-01-01  0.781611  0.766152  0.766152
2007-02-01  0.705615  0.032134  0.032134
2008-01-01  0.026512  0.993124  0.993124
2008-02-01  0.226420  0.033860  0.033860
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have a series with multiindex. Here's another solution for the wanted graph.

```
df.unstack('indentifier').plot.line(subplots=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to those, who need to plot graphs for exploring different levels of aggregation by multiple columns grouping.

```
from numpy.random import randint
from numpy.random import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

levels_bool = np.tile(np.arange(0,2), 100)
levels_groups = np.repeat(np.arange(0,4), 50)
x_axis = np.tile(np.arange(0,10), 20)
values = randint(0,10,200)

stacked = np.stack((levels_bool, levels_groups, x_axis, values), axis=0)
df = pd.DataFrame(stacked.T, columns=['bool', 'groups', 'x_axis', 'values'])

columns = len(df['bool'].unique())
rows = len(df['groups'].unique())
fig, axs = plt.subplots(rows, columns, figsize = (20,20))

y_index_counter = count(0)
groupped_df = df.groupby([ 'groups', 'bool','x_axis']).agg({
    'values': ['min', 'mean', 'median', 'max']
})
for group_name, grp in groupped_df.groupby(['groups']):
    y_index = next(y_index_counter)
    x_index_counter = count(0)
    for boolean, grp2 in grp.groupby(['bool']):
        x_index = next(x_index_counter)
        axs[y_index, x_index].plot(grp2.reset_index()['x_axis'], grp2.reset_index()['values'], 
                                   label=str(key)+str(key2))
        axs[y_index, x_index].set_title("Group:{} Bool:{}".format(group_name, boolean))

ax.legend()
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: groupped by pandas plot]