# Subplot a dataframe according to a column's values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to subplot a dataframe according to the values of the column `id`.

```
datafr = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["timestamp", "id", "col1","col2","col3"], data = [[1,"a", 1, 2, 3], 
                                  [1,"b", 1, 2, 3],
                                  [1,"c", 1, 2, 3],
                                  [2,"a", 1, 2, 3],
                                  [2,"b", 1, 2, 3],
                                  [2,"c", 1, 2, 3]]
                                  )
```

I need to have 3 subplots corresponding to `a, b, c` which are the values of the column `id`. Data in each subplot is data of `col1, col2, col3` .

Is it possible to do this without pivoting my dataframe?

**EDIT :**
I need `timestamp` column in my x_axis.

In the post [Plotting grouped data in same plot using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293028/plotting-grouped-data-in-same-plot-using-pandas) , it is completely the inverse, they want to have one plot for two classes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think so... just use `datafr.drop('timestamp', 1).groupby('id').plot(subplots=True)`

Comment: thank you but I didn't mention that I need timestamp in my x-axis

Comment: Well, ya should've mentioned it.

Comment: Anyway, the fix is minute: `datafr.set_index('timestamp').groupby('id').plot(subplots=True)`

Comment: the duplicate is the inverse of my question

Comment: Err, I'll find a better one. I know your question has been asked before.

Comment: Dupe list updated with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975835/how-to-create-pandas-groupby-plot-with-subplots

Comment: Also, if I'm not wrong, my latest suggestion `datafr.set_index('timestamp').groupby('id').plot(subplots=Tr‌​ue)` should also work for you.