# How does using python Pandas unstack in plt?

Tags: python, pandas

I reference to the information on the Internet.

I would like to painting my data.

```
        id        time           w
5630    39  2018-03-01  841.704067
5631    39  2018-03-02  605.119444
5632    39  2018-03-03  651.337735
5633    39  2018-03-04  595.974252
5634    39  2018-03-05  656.031315
5635    39  2018-03-06  972.101045
5636    39  2018-03-07  660.659986
5637    39  2018-03-08  1225.648122
        .
        .
5685    39  2018-04-25  699.347653
5686    39  2018-04-26  516.267288
5687    39  2018-04-27  621.807574
5688    39  2018-04-28  488.903030
5689    39  2018-04-29  790.637525
5690    39  2018-04-30  457.569811
5691    40  2018-03-01  157.636364
5692    40  2018-03-02  138.759563
5693    40  2018-03-03  209.213996
5694    40  2018-03-04  177.255571
5695    40  2018-03-05  155.696106
        .
        .
5748    40  2018-04-27  133.512968
5749    40  2018-04-28  157.630623
5750    40  2018-04-29  210.996613
5751    40  2018-04-30  120.643963
```

[My reference URL](https://scentellegher.github.io/programming/2017/07/15/pandas-groupby-multiple-columns-plot.html)

I execute this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
df2.groupby(['time','id']).count()['w'].unstack().plot(ax=ax)
```

But my result is strange.

[image]

I would like to painting like this:

I just cut out my sample, but I want to draw it all at once. Overlap or alone.

[image]

How to achieve similar results below.

[image]

I really need your help.Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All working nice, but count is `1` for your data sample, because [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by columns `time` and `id` and for ech pair get size of groups `1`:

```
print (df2.groupby(['time','id']).count()['w'])
time                 id
2017-04-03 18:09:04  39    1
2017-04-03 18:16:04  39    1
2017-04-03 18:23:04  39    1
2017-04-03 18:30:04  39    1
2017-04-03 18:37:04  39    1
2017-04-03 18:44:04  40    1
2017-04-03 18:51:04  40    1
2017-04-03 18:58:04  40    1
2017-04-03 19:05:04  40    1
2017-04-03 19:12:04  40    1
Name: w, dtype: int64
```

Then reshaped output is `DataFrame` with 2 columns filled by `1` and `NaN`s for values which not exist in pairs:

```
df = df2.groupby(['time','id']).count()['w'].unstack()
print (df)
id                    39   40
time                         
2017-04-03 18:09:04  1.0  NaN
2017-04-03 18:16:04  1.0  NaN
2017-04-03 18:23:04  1.0  NaN
2017-04-03 18:30:04  1.0  NaN
2017-04-03 18:37:04  1.0  NaN
2017-04-03 18:44:04  NaN  1.0
2017-04-03 18:51:04  NaN  1.0
2017-04-03 18:58:04  NaN  1.0
2017-04-03 19:05:04  NaN  1.0
2017-04-03 19:12:04  NaN  1.0
```

If values are dates only, so need `Grouper` by `7d` for week or `MS` for start of month instead `time` columns (also added parameter `fill_value=0` for replace `NaN`s to `0`):

```
df = df2.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='7d', key='time'),'id'])['w'].count().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
buildingid  39  40
reporttime        
2018-03-01   7   5
2018-03-08   1   0
2018-04-19   1   0
2018-04-26   5   4
```

So finally your code looks like:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
df2.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='7d', key='time'),'id'])['w'].count().unstack(fill_value=0).plot(ax=ax)
```

Comment: @@jezrael, Can suggest me what I can do to achieve similar functionality on the reference site? I created a sample of a similar reference site and executed it and I got the same result.

Comment: I think yes, give me some time.

Comment: @Linminxiang - I dont see your real data, so my solution suggest count values per days. But it plot nothing if data only for one day, then neecd change `freq=d` to `freq=1h` or similar.

Comment: @@jezrael, I have update my data. My data like this. By the way, the code just mentioned can't draw things. Can you help me?

Comment: @Linminxiang - Sure, then is possible aggregate values, e.g. plot values per 7 days or by month by `freq='7d'` or `freq='MS'`.

Comment: @@jezrael, Thank you very much for your help. Obviously this method and result are not what I want. What I want is a daily 'w' visualization of each id. Like this, my updated data.

Comment: hmmm, do you need count? Not `sum` like `df2.groupby(['reporttime','buildingid'])['w'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0).plot(ax=ax)` ?

Comment: And if need plot all data with no groups `df2.groupby(['reporttime'])['w'].sum().plot()` should help.  But still not sure if need `count` or `sum`

Comment: @@jezrael, Ooh,I'm so sorry. I always got it wrong. Can you advise me how to separate the display? Thank you patiently for the answer.

Comment: @Linminxiang - ` how to separate the display` not sure if understamd, can you explain more?

Comment: @Linminxiang - It is more complicated, need more time.

Comment: @@jezrael - I am sorry I have been troubled you.

Comment: @Linminxiang - Yes, I think need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29976189/2901002), only change `grouped = df.groupby('a')
rowlength = grouped.ngroups/2` to `grouped = df2.groupby('id')
rowlength = grouped.ngroups//2`

Comment: oops, need `grouped = df2.set_index('time').groupby('id')`

Comment: @@jezrael -  Ok, I try it. Thank you.