# Subplots for density distribution

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, distribution, subplot

I have this dataset:

[image]

I would like to have the density curves along the day for each day and each shop.
For now, I have everything on one graph, but it is quite messy. What do you think is the best way to divide it into 4 subplots for each of the 4 shops? I tried various methods but each time I got the same plots on the 4 different graphs.

```
`plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
 df.groupby([df.shopping_center_id, 'day']).hour.plot.kde(ind=[j for j in range(25)]);
 plt.legend()`
```

Actual graph:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create Pandas groupby plot with subplots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975835/how-to-create-pandas-groupby-plot-with-subplots)

Comment: Hello Richie, thank you for the link. I had already seen it but I didn't manage solving my problem using this method. Even if the final graphs are what I am looking for, the dataset is quite different because I have a feature more, haven't I?